# Select columns from two different tables using a sub-query - not a join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a query with a sub-query that looks like this

```
USE AP

SELECT VendorName, InvoiceDate, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceTotal
FROM Invoices AS main
WHERE InvoiceTotal >
    (SELECT MAX(InvoiceTotal)
     FROM Invoices AS sub
     WHERE VendorID = 121 AND sub.VendorID = main.VendorID)
ORDER BY VendorName, InvoiceTotal DESC
```

I'm getting an error mark under the vendorName column since its not in the Invoices table. It's in the Vendors table, but I'm not allowed to join the two tables. Is there a way to have the column recognized and provided in the result set?

with a join and no results

```
USE AP

SELECT VendorName, InvoiceDate, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceTotal
FROM Invoices AS main JOIN Vendors AS v
    ON main.VendorID = v.VendorID
WHERE InvoiceTotal >
    (SELECT MAX(InvoiceTotal)
     FROM Invoices AS sub
     WHERE VendorID = 121 AND sub.VendorID = main.VendorID)
ORDER BY VendorName, InvoiceTotal DESC
```

Comment: Why are you not "allowed" to use `JOIN`s?

Comment: SQL selecting from a table without `join's`? Surely that's like trying to play football without feet?

Comment: I don't know my professor has messed up on a couple of these questions before, if that's the only way to do it then I'll do it that way. These assignments are geared around sub queries but if its not possible then maybe I'm wrong. Anyway I tried it with a join and edited the OP but I'm getting no results. I'm obviously a newbie:(

Comment: I'm assuming you're getting an error along the lines of VendorID cannot be bound? The `sub.VendorID = main.VendorID` is a weird way of supplementing a join...perhaps remove that condition and see how it does? I don't see how that can matter in your query since it appears to already be filtered (`VendorID = 121`). EDIT: I think your query is wrong...your subquery references Invoices table, not Vendors..that threw me off. Validate this?

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** don't want to use joins, you might try a nested select (not sure if that's the correct term).
For example:

```
SELECT (SELECT v.VendorName FROM vendors v WHERE main.VendorID = v.VendorID) AS VendorName,
       main.InvoiceDate,
       main.InvoiceNumber,
       main.InvoiceTotal
FROM   Invoices AS main
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Without joins, you can achieve it like below:

```
USE AP
SELECT 
    (SELECT VendorName FROM vendors v where v.vendorid = main.vendorid) VendorName, 
    InvoiceDate, 
    InvoiceNumber, 
    InvoiceTotal
FROM Invoices AS main
WHERE InvoiceTotal >
    (SELECT MAX(InvoiceTotal)
     FROM Invoices AS sub
     WHERE VendorID = 121 )
ORDER BY VendorName, InvoiceTotal DESC
```

If you are after finding invoice with max InvoiceTotal, then use the below query:

```
USE AP

SELECT 
    (SELECT VendorName FROM vendors v where v.vendorid = main.vendorid) VendorName, 
    InvoiceDate, 
    InvoiceNumber, 
    InvoiceTotal
FROM Invoices AS main
WHERE InvoiceTotal >=
    (SELECT MAX(InvoiceTotal)
     FROM Invoices AS sub
     WHERE sub.VendorID = main.VendorID)
ORDER BY VendorName, InvoiceTotal DESC
```

DB Fiddle is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b2725d9016706985e0b5207873526152).